# Bootstrap 4 Datatablejs in Angular4 CLI project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, datatables

I just created a web app in Angular 4 with the Angular CLI utility.

I want to display in one page of my web app one table with DatatableJs.
I got it, but the style is horrible.

[image: This my result]

I think it's due to a dependency installation problem. I installed Bootstrap 4 and [DataTables core](https://datatables.net/download/npm) via npm.

This my configuration in **.angular-cli.json** file:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To use Bootstrap 4 with DataTablejs use npm to install Bootstrap 4 package.

```
npm install --save datatables.net-bs4
```

Then, Update ".angular-cli.json" files Styles and scripts properties as below.

```
{
 ........
  "apps": [
    { 
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        //for bootstrap4
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
        //for bootstrap4
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"
      ]
      ...
    }
  ],
 .....
}
```

after above changes, we can use bootstrap4 classes to shows table like a bootstrap4 table for example

```
<table id='table' datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the datatables bootstrap4 css.

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css

Comment: I put this in my index.html but still not work.
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"/>

Comment: remove dataTables.bootstrap.css from the angular-cli.json and recompile the resources, you probably have a conflict with both on the page

Comment: also, this is the link for bootstrap4 css that is used by datatables in their examples. //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: Ok..i have these two references in my index
   <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alp‌​ha.6/css/bootstrap.c‌​ss"/>

But not work.:(
I also removed dataTables.bootstrap.css from config file.